How to add ASCII color recognition for an ARM os?
I want to create my own operating system. In this OS, I have an edit mode for modifying file data (currently only in RAM). Here full code of this os:
#include "editor.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "strings.h"

void edit_file(File *file){
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    uart_puts("\r\nEntering edit mode. Press Ctrl + Q to save and exit.\r\n");
    
    if (file -> content[0] != '\0'){
        uart_puts(file->content);
        index = my_strlen(file->content);
    }
    while(1){
        c = uart_getc();
        
        if(c == 17){ //Ctrl + Q
            file->content[index] = '\0';
            uart_puts("\r\nFile saved and exited edit mode.\r\n");
            break;
        }else if (c == '\b' || c == 127){
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b \b");
            }
        }else if (c == '\r'){
            if(index < MAX_FILE_SIZE -1){
                file-> content[index++]='\n';
                uart_putc('\r');
                uart_putc('\n');
            }
        }else{
            if(index < MAX_FILE_SIZE -1){
                file->content[index++] = c;
                uart_putc(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

Implements a simple text editor within the system. Includes functions to enter edit mode and capture user input. Supports editing existing file content or creating new content. Handles special input like: Ctrl + Q to save and exit edit mode. Backspace and carriage return. Updates the file's content in memory(RAM).
Here editor.h:
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H

#include "file_system.h"

void edit_file(File *file);

#endif

Includes the declaration of edit_file(File *file).
Includes necessary headers: file_system.h. Here file_system.c:
#include "file_system.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "editor.h"
#include "strings.h"

FileSystem fs;

void init_fs(){
    fs.file_count = 0;
}
int create_directory(const char *name){
    if(fs.file_count >= MAX_FILES){
        uart_puts("FileSystem is full, cannot create directory.\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
        if(my_strcmp(fs.files[i].name, name) == 0){
            uart_puts("Directory already exist.\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    my_strcpy(fs.files[fs.file_count].name, name);
    fs.files[fs.file_count].is_directory = 1;
    fs.file_count++;
    uart_puts("Directory created. \r\n");
    return 0;
}
int create_file(const char *name){
    if(fs.file_count >= MAX_FILES){
        uart_puts("FileSystem is full, cannot crete file. \r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
        if(my_strcmp(fs.files[i].name, name) == 0){
            uart_puts("File already exist.\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    my_strcpy(fs.files[fs.file_count].name, name);
    fs.files[fs.file_count].is_directory = 0;
    fs.files[fs.file_count].content[0] = '\0';
    fs.file_count++;
    uart_puts("File created.\r\n");
    return 0;
}

void list_directory(){
    uart_puts("Directories:\r\n");
    if(fs.file_count == 0){
        uart_puts("No directories.\r\n");
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
            if(fs.files[i].is_directory){
                uart_puts(fs.files[i].name);
                uart_putc('\r');
                uart_putc('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}

File *find_file(const char *name){
    for (int i = 0; i < fs.file_count; i++){
        if(!fs.files[i].is_directory && my_strcmp(fs.files[i].name, name) == 0){
            return &fs.files[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void process_command(const char *cmd, int *debug_mode){
    uart_puts("\r\n");
    
    if(my_strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0){
        uart_puts("Avaible commands: help, echo <message>, debug on, debug off, mkdir <name>, ls, mkf <file> edit <file>. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "echo ", 5) == 0){
        uart_puts(cmd + 5);
        uart_putc('\r');
        uart_putc('\n');
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug on") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 1;
        uart_puts("Debug mode enabled. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strcmp(cmd, "debug off") == 0){
        *debug_mode = 0;
        uart_puts("Debug mode disable. \r\n");
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "mkdir ", 6) == 0){
        create_directory(cmd + 6);
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "edit ", 5) == 0){
        File *file = find_file(cmd + 5);
        if (file){
            edit_file(file);
        }else{
            uart_puts("File not found.\n\r");
        }
    }else if(my_strncmp(cmd, "mkf ", 4) == 0){
        create_file(cmd + 4);
    }else if (my_strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0){
        list_directory();
    }else{
        uart_puts("Unknown command. \r\n");
    }
}

void print_command(const char *cmd, int debug_mode){
    if(debug_mode){
        uart_puts("\r\nReceived command: ");
        uart_puts(cmd);
        uart_putc('\r');
        uart_putc('\n');
    }
}

Defines the FileSystem and initializes it with init_fs().
Functions to:

Create directories (create_directory).
Create files (create_file).
List directories (list_directory).
Find files (find_file).
Process commands from the user (process_command).

Command processing supports commands like help, echo, debug on/off, mkdir, ls, mkf, edit.
Provides feedback via UART.
and file_system.h:
#ifndef FILE_SYSTEM_H
#define FILE_SYSTEM_H

#define MAX_FILES 16
#define MAX_NAME_LEGTH 32
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 1024

#include <stddef.h>

typedef unsigned long size_t;

typedef struct{
    char name [MAX_NAME_LEGTH];
    int is_directory;
    char content[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
} File;

typedef struct{
    File files[MAX_FILES];
    int file_count;
} FileSystem;

void init_fs();
int create_directory(const char *name);
int create_file(const char *name);
void list_directory();
File *find_file(const char *name);
void process_command(const char *cmd, int *debug_mode);
void print_command(const char *cmd, int debug_mode);

#endif

Header file for file_system.c, defining structures and function prototypes.
Details:
Constants:

MAX_FILES: Maximum number of files/directories.
MAX_NAME_LENGTH: Maximum length of file/directory names.
MAX_FILE_SIZE: Maximum size of file content.
Type Definitions:
File: Represents a file or directory with name, type, and content.
FileSystem: Contains an array of File and a file count.
Function Declarations:
Initialization, creation, listing, finding, and processing functions related to the file system.

memmp - it is just a linker:
ENTRY(_main)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x40000000;  /* Начальный адрес загрузки */

    .startup : { strap.o(.text) }  /* Секция для инициализации (например, strap.o) */

    .text : {
        *(.text)  /* Код программы */
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)  /* Инициализированные данные */
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss COMMON)  /* Неиницилизированные данные */
    }

    /* Секция для хранения файловой системы */
    .fs_section (NOLOAD) : {
        *(.fs_section)  /* Секция для файловой системы */
    }

    . = ALIGN(8);  /* Выравнивание */
    . = . + 0x1000; /* 4kB памяти для стека */
    stack_top = .;  /* Указатель на верх стека */
}

Here is the main file:
#include "uart.h"
#include "file_system.h"
#include "strings.h"

#define COMMAND_HISTORY_SiZE 10 

void notmain(void){
    char c;
    char command[100];
    int index = 0;
    int debug_mode = 0;//0 - debug off, 1 - on
    
    char command_history[COMMAND_HISTORY_SiZE][100];
    int command_history_count = 0;
    int command_history_pos = -1;
    uart_puts("UART test... \n");
    init_fs();
    while(1){
        c = uart_getc();
        if(c == '\r'){
            command[index] = '\0';
            if(command[0] != '\0'){
                if(command_history_count < COMMAND_HISTORY_SiZE){
                    my_strcpy(command_history[command_history_count++], command);
                }else{
                    for (int i = 0; i < COMMAND_HISTORY_SiZE; i++){
                        my_strcpy(command_history[i-1], command_history[i]);
                    }
                    my_strcpy(command_history[COMMAND_HISTORY_SiZE - 1], command);
                }
            }
            command_history_pos = command_history_count;
            print_command(command, debug_mode);
            process_command(command, &debug_mode);
            index = 0;
        } else if (c == '\b' || c == 127){
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b \b");
            }
        } else if(c == 27){
            char seq[2];
            seq[0] = uart_getc();
            seq[1] = uart_getc();
            if(seq[0] == '['){
                if(seq[1]=='A'){
                    if(command_history_pos > 0){
                        command_history_pos--;
                        while(index > 0){
                            uart_puts("\b \b");
                            index--;
                        }
                        my_strcpy(command, command_history[command_history_pos]);
                        index = my_strlen(command);
                        uart_puts(command);
                    }
                }else if(seq[1] == 'B'){
                    if(command_history_pos < command_history_count - 1){
                        command_history_pos++;
                        while(index > 0){
                            uart_puts("\b \b");
                            index--;
                        }
                        my_strcpy(command, command_history[command_history_pos]);
                        index = my_strlen(command);
                        uart_puts(command);
                    }else if(command_history_pos == command_history_count - 1){
                        while(index > 0){
                            uart_puts("\b \b");
                            index--;
                        }
                        command[0] = '\0';
                    }
                }
            }   
        }else{
            if(index < sizeof(command)-1){
                command[index++] = c;
                uart_putc(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

Functions:

Initializes UART communication and the file system.
Implements a command-line interface (CLI) that:
Reads user input via UART.
Maintains a command history (supports navigating with up/down arrows).
Processes commands using process_command.
Handles special characters and key sequences (e.g., backspace, arrow keys).
Supports debug mode to print received commands.

Here assembly code (strap.s):
.global _main
_main:
    ldr x30, =stack_top
    mov sp, x30
    bl notmain
    b .
    

Functions:

Global label _main as the entry point.
Sets up the stack pointer (sp) using stack_top from the linker script.
Calls notmain to start the main program.
Enters an infinite loop after notmain returns.

Also I wrote own strings.s file:
#include "strings.h"


int my_strlen(const char *str){
    int len = 0;
    while(*str++){
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)){
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}
int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n){
    while (n > 0){
        if(*s1 != *s2){
            return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
        }
        if (*s1 == '\0'){
            return 0;
        }
        s1++;
        s2++;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
void my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src){
    while(*src){
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}

It includes strcpy, strncmp, strcmp, strlen.
Also I have header file:
#ifndef STRINGS_H
#define STRINGS_H

#include <stddef.h>

int my_strlen(const char *str);
int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
void my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);

#endif

Also I have uart.c file for I/O recognasion:
#include "uart.h"
#include <stdint.h>

void uart_putc(char c){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<5)){
        
    }
    *UARTDR = c;
}
char uart_getc(){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<4)){
            
    }
    return *UARTDR & 0xFF;
}
void uart_puts(const char *str){
    while (*str){
        uart_putc(*str++);
    }
}

Functions of this file:

Send a single character (uart_putc).
Receive a single character (uart_getc).
Send a string (uart_puts).
Uses memory-mapped I/O to interact with UART hardware registers. Waits for UART buffers to be ready before sending or receiving data.

I am trying to update my editor which highlites C/C++ keywords, numbers and semicolon. I trying to make it in editor.c like that:
#include "editor.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "strings.h"

// ANSI color codes
#define COLOR_RESET "\033[0m"
#define COLOR_KEYWORD "\033[31m"  // Red color for keywords and semicolons
#define COLOR_NUMBER "\033[32m"   // Green color for numbers
// You can adjust the colors as needed

int is_c_or_cpp_file(const char *filename){
    int len = my_strlen(filename);
    if(len >= 2 && my_strcmp(filename + len - 2, ".c") == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(len >= 4 && my_strcmp(filename + len - 4, ".cpp") == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

const char* keywords[] = {
    "int", "char", "if", "else", "for", "while", "return", "void", "include",
    "define", "struct", "typedef", "enum", "static", "const", "unsigned",
    "signed", "long", "short", "float", "double", "do", "switch", "case",
    "break", "continue", "default", "goto", "sizeof", "volatile", "register",
    "extern", "auto", "union", "inline"
};
#define NUM_KEYWORDS (sizeof(keywords)/sizeof(keywords[0]))

int is_keyword(const char *word){
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYWORDS; i++){
        if(my_strcmp(word, keywords[i]) == 0){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int is_number(const char *word){
    int i = 0;
    if(word[0] == '-' || word[0] == '+') i++;  // handle sign
    int has_digits = 0;
    for(; word[i]; i++){
        if(word[i] >= '0' && word[i] <= '9'){
            has_digits = 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return has_digits;
}

void move_cursor_back(int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        uart_puts("\b \b");
    }
}

void output_with_syntax_highlighting(const char *content){
    int i = 0;
    char word[50];
    int word_index = 0;
    char c;
    while((c = content[i]) != '\0'){
        if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == '_') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')){
            if(word_index < sizeof(word) - 1){
                word[word_index++] = c;
            }
            // We don't output yet
        }else{
            word[word_index] = '\0';

            if(is_keyword(word)){
                uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
                uart_puts(word);
                uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
            }else if(is_number(word)){
                uart_puts(COLOR_NUMBER);
                uart_puts(word);
                uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
            }else{
                uart_puts(word);
            }
            word_index = 0;

            if(c == ';'){
                uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
                uart_putc(c);
                uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
            }else{
                uart_putc(c);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    // Output any remaining word
    if(word_index > 0){
        word[word_index] = '\0';
        if(is_keyword(word)){
            uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
            uart_puts(word);
            uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
        }else if(is_number(word)){
            uart_puts(COLOR_NUMBER);
            uart_puts(word);
            uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
        }else{
            uart_puts(word);
        }
    }
}

void edit_file(File *file){
    char c;
    int index = 0;
    uart_puts("\r\nEntering edit mode. Press Ctrl + Q to save and exit.\r\n");
    
    int syntax_highlighting = 0;
    if(is_c_or_cpp_file(file->name)){
        syntax_highlighting = 1;
    }

    if (file->content[0] != '\0'){
        if(syntax_highlighting){
            output_with_syntax_highlighting(file->content);
        }else{
            uart_puts(file->content);
        }
        index = my_strlen(file->content);
    }
    
    char word[50];
    int word_index = 0;

    while(1){
        c = uart_getc();
        
        if(c == 17){ //Ctrl + Q
            file->content[index] = '\0';
            uart_puts("\r\nFile saved and exited edit mode.\r\n");
            break;
        }else if (c == '\b' || c == 127){
            if(index > 0){
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b \b");

                // Handle word buffer
                if(word_index > 0){
                    word_index--;
                }
            }
        }else if (c == '\r'){
            if(index < MAX_FILE_SIZE -1){
                file->content[index++]='\n';
                uart_putc('\r');
                uart_putc('\n');
                word[word_index] = '\0';

                // Process the word at end of line
                if(syntax_highlighting && word_index > 0){
                    if(is_keyword(word)){
                        move_cursor_back(word_index);
                        uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
                        uart_puts(word);
                        uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
                    }else if(is_number(word)){
                        move_cursor_back(word_index);
                        uart_puts(COLOR_NUMBER);
                        uart_puts(word);
                        uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
                    }
                    word_index = 0;
                }else{
                    word_index = 0;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(index < MAX_FILE_SIZE -1){
                file->content[index++] = c;
                
                if(syntax_highlighting){
                    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == '_') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')){
                        if(word_index < sizeof(word) - 1){
                            word[word_index++] = c;
                        }
                        uart_putc(c);  // Temporarily output the character
                    }else{
                        // Non-alphanumeric character
                        word[word_index] = '\0';

                        // Check for keyword or number
                        if(is_keyword(word)){
                            move_cursor_back(word_index);
                            uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
                            uart_puts(word);
                            uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
                        }else if(is_number(word)){
                            move_cursor_back(word_index);
                            uart_puts(COLOR_NUMBER);
                            uart_puts(word);
                            uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
                        }
                        word_index = 0;

                        // Handle semicolons
                        if(c == ';'){
                            uart_puts(COLOR_KEYWORD);
                            uart_putc(c);
                            uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
                        }else{
                            uart_putc(c);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    uart_putc(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

and header file:
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H

#include "file_system.h"

// Визначення ANSI-кодів кольорів
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\033[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\033[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\033[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\033[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\033[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\033[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\033[0m"

void edit_file(File *file);
// Прототипи функцій
void display_with_syntax_highlighting(const char *content);
void re_render_current_line(const char *content, int length);
int is_letter_or_digit(char c);
int is_keyword(const char *word);
#endif

I also added to notmain.c little func for testing colors:
void test_ansi_colors() {
    uart_puts("\033[31mЦей текст повинен бути червоним\033[0m\r\n");
    uart_puts("\033[32mЦей текст повинен бути зеленим\033[0m\r\n");
    uart_puts("\033[34mЦей текст повинен бути синім\033[0m\r\n");
}

I'm testing using qemu command:
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 128 -serial mon:stdio -kernel os.bin

When I launched it, it was colored:

But, when I created file, and tried to edit it, I have a little issue:

Why are the keywords not highlighted?
So, in conclusion, what I need:
Add keyword highlighter for .c/.cpp files and for .java file (just else if statement). Also it must highlight in green color text which in " " (double quotes) and numbers (4, 4412, 2_000_000, 2E+1)

Syntax highlighting isn't something an operating system would do, it's something you do in a text editor application.

@Barmar, i showed u full code of editor

But you said this is for implementing an operating system, not an editor.

yep it is for operation system, like nano in linux but this editor i isntalled from the box

Where have you defined ANSI_COLOR_BLUE ? You should prefer switch case to these many if statements too though

@Mike, i edited full question

Your code works perfectly for me. Is it when you try editing ?

@Mike, in editor mode C++ keywords are not highliting for me

The same as in C keywords ? Is it when you try editing, like writing a new keyword ?

@Mike, I added screenshot which shows that C keywords like int is not highlighting. Yes it only when I trying to edit file, because I need only highlighting in editor mode

Full code ;
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef __ARM_ARCH
#include <termios.h> //termios, TCSANOW, ECHO, ICANON
#include <unistd.h>  //STDIN_FILENO
#else
#error Not compiling for ARM
#endif // __ARM_ARCH
#include <stdio.h>

#define uart_puts(s) fputs(s, stdout)
#define uart_putc(c) putc(c, stdout)
#define uart_getc getchar

#define MAX_FILES 16
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 32
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 1024

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    int is_directory;
    char content[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
} File;

typedef struct
{
    File files[MAX_FILES];
    int file_count;
} FileSystem;

int my_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (*str++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2))
    {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}

int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    while (n > 0 && *s1 && (*s1 == *s2))
    {
        s1++;
        s2++;
        n--;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}

void my_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    while (*src)
        *dest++ = *src++;
    *dest = '\0';
}

#define COLOR_RESET "\033[0m"
#define COLOR_KEYWORD "\033[35m"
#define COLOR_NUMBER "\033[36m"

bool is_c_or_cpp_file(const char *filename)
{
    int len = my_strlen(filename);
    return (len >= 2 && my_strcmp(filename + len - 2, ".c") == 0) || (len >= 4 && my_strcmp(filename + len - 4, ".cpp") == 0);
}

static const char *keywords[] = {
    "int", "char", "if", "else", "for", "while", "return", "void", "include",
    "define", "struct", "typedef", "enum", "static", "const", "unsigned",
    "signed", "long", "short", "float", "double", "do", "switch", "case",
    "break", "continue", "default", "goto", "sizeof", "volatile", "register",
    "extern", "auto", "union", "inline"};
#define NUM_KEYWORDS (sizeof(keywords) / sizeof(keywords[0]))

bool is_keyword(const char *word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYWORDS; i++)
    {
        if (my_strcmp(word, keywords[i]) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool is_number(const char *word)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (word[0] == '-' || word[0] == '+')
        i++; // handle sign

    for (; word[i]; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] < '0' || word[i] > '9')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void move_cursor_back(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        uart_puts("\b \b");
}

void highlight(const char *s, const int l, const char *colour)
{
    move_cursor_back(l);
    uart_puts(colour);
    uart_puts(s);
    uart_puts(COLOR_RESET);
}

void output_with_syntax_highlighting(const char *content)
{
    int i = 0;
    char word[50];
    int word_index = 0;
    char c;

    while ((c = content[i]) != '\0')
    {
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == '_') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
        {
            if (word_index < sizeof(word) - 1)
                word[word_index++] = c;
            // We don't output yet
        }
        else
        {
            word[word_index] = '\0';

            if (is_keyword(word))
                highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_KEYWORD);
            else if (is_number(word))
                highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_NUMBER);
            else
                uart_puts(word);

            word_index = 0;

            if (c == ';')
                highlight(&c, 0, COLOR_NUMBER);
            else
                uart_putc(c);
        }
        i++;
    }
    // Output any remaining word
    if (word_index > 0)
    {
        word[word_index] = '\0';
        if (is_keyword(word))
            highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_KEYWORD);
        else if (is_number(word))
            highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_NUMBER);
        else
            uart_puts(word);
    }
}

void edit_file(File *file)
{
    int c;
    int index = 0;
    uart_puts("\r\nEntering edit mode. Press Ctrl + Q to save and exit.\r\n");

    int syntax_highlighting = 0;
    if (is_c_or_cpp_file(file->name))
    {
        syntax_highlighting = 1;
    }

    if (file->content[0] != '\0')
    {
        if (syntax_highlighting)
            output_with_syntax_highlighting(file->content);
        else
            uart_puts(file->content);
        index = my_strlen(file->content);
    }

    char word[2048];
    int word_index = 0;

#ifdef __ARM_ARCH
    static struct termios oldt, newt;

    /*tcgetattr gets the parameters of the current terminal
    STDIN_FILENO will tell tcgetattr that it should write the settings
    of stdin to oldt*/
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    /*now the settings will be copied*/
    newt = oldt;

    /*ICANON normally takes care that one line at a time will be processed
    that means it will return if it sees a "\n" or an EOF or an EOL*/
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);

    /*Those new settings will be set to STDIN
    TCSANOW tells tcsetattr to change attributes immediately. */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
#endif // __ARM_ARCH
    while (1)
    {
        c = uart_getc();
        // getchar();
        printf("0x%02x\n", c);

        switch (c)
        {
        case '\b':
        case 0x7f:
            if (index > 0)
            {
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b\b\b   \b\b\b");

                // Handle word buffer
                if (word_index > 0)
                {
                    word_index--;
                }
            }
            break;
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            if (index < 255 - 1 && word_index > 0)
                file->content[++index] = '\n';
            break;
        default:
            if (index < MAX_FILE_SIZE - 1)
            {
                file->content[index++] = c;
                // break;

                if (syntax_highlighting)
                {
                    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == '_') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
                    {
                        if (word_index < sizeof(word) - 1)
                            word[word_index++] = c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Non-alphanumeric character
                        word[word_index++] = '\0';

                        // Check for keyword or number
                        bool highlighted = false;

                        if ((highlighted = is_keyword(word)))
                            highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_KEYWORD);
                        else if ((highlighted = is_number(word)))
                            highlight(word, word_index, COLOR_NUMBER);
                        if (c == ';')
                            highlight((char *)&c, 0, COLOR_KEYWORD);
                        else if (c != '\n' && highlighted)
                            uart_putc(c);

                        word_index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
#ifdef __ARM_ARCH
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
#endif // __ARM_ARCH
}

int main()
{
    File file = {
        "main.c",
        0,
        "int main() {\n\treturn 0;\n}\n"};
    edit_file(&file);

    return 0;
}

What I changed:

Change settings to stdin so it catches the character immediately. Inspired by this answer
DEL (0x7f) needs 3 \b because it's caught as being ^?\x7f.
keywords defined as static const char *

For better readability:

bool instead of int
New highlight() function and is_c_or_cpp_file() shortened
switch cases instead of chained if statements

Demo here
Lemme know if it works for you too, maybe the behavior is different on your emulator.

tcgetattr and tcsetattr... these functions are part of the POSIX terminal control interface . When i  compiling with and targeting an ARM architecture the standard C library and POSIX APIs are not available. This results in undefined references during linking<termios.h> and -nostdlib

can u write full code which u tested perhaps?

Can you try adding the flag -std=gnu99 ?

the same trouble, not working
